# Proof that $G$ is regular

Tags: graph-theory

Proof that if $G$ graph doesn't contain triangle, and every $2$ non-neighbour vertexes have only $2$ common neighbour vertexes, then $G$ is regular ($G$ s each vertex's degree is equal to the same number).

I understood this. if it doesn't contain any triangle, it means that $$\left|E(g)\right| \le \left[\frac{|V(g)|^2}{4}\right]$$ But it doesn't help as I see. Any Ideas?

Comment: I assume you want $G$ connected, and that you mean that any two non-adjacent vertices have exactly two common neighbours?

Comment: No, I want G to be regular, not connected, and yes I mean that any two non-adjacent vertices have exaclty 2 common neighbours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose two vertices $a$ and $b$ are neighbours.  I claim $a$ and $b$ have the same degree.  It is enough to show that $a$ has at least as many neighbours as $b$.  Say $a$ has $k$ neighbours $c_1, \ldots, c_{k}$ besides $b$.  Since there are no triangles,
these are not neighbours of $b$. So $c_i$ and $b$ have two common neighbours: one is $a$, and let the other be $d_i$.  These must be distinct, as $d_i$ and $a$ (which can't be neighbours because there are no triangles) have only two common neighbours $b$ and $c_i$.  Thus $b$ has (at least) $k$ neighbours besides $a$.

Now suppose vertices $a$ and $b$ are not neighbours.  Again, I claim $b$ has at least as many neighbours as $a$.  They have two common neighbours $c$ and $d$, which are not neighbours since there are no triangles.  Suppose $a$ has $k$ other neighbours $e_1, \ldots, e_k$.

For any $j$, $e_j$ can't be a neighbour of any of $c$, $d$, or $b$.  $e_j$ and $c$ have $a$ as common neighbour, so they must have one other common neighbour $f_j$, which can't be a neighbour of $a$, $b$ or $c$.  Moreover the $f_j$ for different $j$ must be distinct: if $f_i = f_j$, $a$ and $f_i$ would have at least three common neighbours $e_i$, $e_j$ and $c$. 
$f_j$ and $b$ are not neighbours and have $d$ as a common neighbour, so they must have another common neighbour $g_j$.  Again, the $g_j$ must be distinct.  Thus $b$ has at least $k$ other neighbours $g_1, \ldots, g_k$.

Comment: For another approach to the second part of the proof: if adjacent vertices have the same degree, then degree is constant on each connected component, and if any two vertices have two common neighbors, then the graph is connected.

Comment: The same proof that shows $a$ has at least as many as $b$ shows that $b$ has at least as many as $a$.